# Cannot access my scm url

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm working through the App Service [getting started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started) with Azure CLI 2.0 Preview but at the stage we do a ``git push``` the host is unresolved. Indeed when I ping it I get no response, even if I add port 443 - which I'm not sure windows ping accepts.

When I log into the portal I see everything appears to be set up. At least the git clone URL is identical to what I have added as a git remote. Namely

https://my@email.com.com@my-cli-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/my-cli-app.git

I use the UK West centre which is the closest to me. Anyway, I can't imagine there are DNS propagation delays to worry about

Have I missed something obvious?

thanks

PS one thing that I don't believe can be related is I have a number of subscriptions but as they are not specified in the given commands it picked a random one it Happens to be a MSDN subscription which has expired but works with Azure.

Comment: I'm wondering of it is the @in my username but my azure username is my email address as that is also my Microsoft account username. And has been for a long time.

Comment: [this is messy as it appears formatting is ignored in comments ] Having just rummaged around the portal I think I see the issue. namely the instructions for step 3 are unclear. 

> Set the deployment user for App Service. You will deploy code using these credentials later.

The credential required are NOT your Azure user, which is the natural understanding, but a NEW username to specify as the deploy user that azure compares against the URL. The portal explains that must start wit ha letter and be letters, number, hyphen and underscores

Have I got that right?

Comment: Now I am stuck as re running the ```az appservice web deployment user set --user-name <username> --password <password>``` erros with 400 bad request but the user I tries is not available in portal.

Comment: Surely the usernames do not have to be globally unique? Using a new name and password in the portal, I am also able to set with the CLI without that error. This really could be made clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem sorted out by leaving the "my@email.com.com" -part out of the "git remote add" -command. When making "git push" I was asked for the credentials. The command for creating the alias is then:

```
git remote add azure https://my-cli-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/my-cli-app.git
```